# How to control font-size style separately for label and choices text for selectInput in Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, user-controls, shiny

I have a `selectInput` widget in Shiny.

I **want to control the font-size separately** for both the `label` argument, and for the input text of the widget itself (i.e., the text of the `choices` and `selected` arguments).

The initial [style-less] output looks like this:

```
selectInput(inputId = "inId", label = "Different Font Size...", choices = "...From This")
```

[image]

I tried using `div()` like so:

```
div(style = "font-size: 8px", 
    selectInput(inputId = "inId", label = "Different Font Size...", choices = "...From This")

)
```

Which shrinks both the `label` text and the input text (i.e., the text from `choices`).

[image]

- Note: this is in contrast to using this `div(style = ...)` approach for `textInput`, which instead only impacts the `label` text (and not the input text).

  - In this instance, I would *then* use `tags$style("#inId {font-size:8px;}")` following the `textInput` function to modify the input font size separately.

    ```
    div(style = "font-size: 8px", 
        textInput(inputId = "inId", label = "Different Font Size...", value = "...From This")
    ), tags$style("#inId {font-size:14px;}")
    ```

However, this does *not* work using `selectInput()`.

- Designating a `tag$style(...)` following a `div(style = ...)` wrapper doesn't seem to do anything to the resulting text style.

  ```
    div(style = "font-size: 8px", 
        selectInput(inputId = "inId", label = "Different Font Size...", choices = "...From This")
    ), tags$style("#inId {font-size:14px;}")
    )
  ```

So how do I do this?

**How do I control the text styling (specifically font-size) *separately* for the `label` and `choices` text for a `selectInput` widget using Shiny?**

- Again, my goal is to achieve the ability to do the following:

  [image]

---

<sup>If it matters: I'm using shiny_1.0.3 with R version 3.4.0</sup>

Answer (score 11):

You can wrap both the whole `selectInput()` as well as the **label itself** in a `div()` with separate font-sizes. The style of the label will overwrite the style of the outer div.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(style = "font-size:20px;",
      selectInput(inputId = "inId", label = div(style = "font-size:80px", "Different Font Size..."), 
                  choices = c("...From This", "Test")
                  )
      )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

I hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Oddly, this seems to work well for me unless I have selectize = F, and then it doesn't work for the choices...any ideas on that one?